# JComponent added to JPanel doesn't appear?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, game-development, jcomponent

I have searched a lot for this problem and did find similar problems but not exactly this so nothing has worked yet.

I am making a game like Vampire Survivors and right now I am trying to get the playable character to appear on the screen.

My method is to create a JPanel that has a picture and is essentially the background. Then I add the HeroComponent over it and also the MonstersComponent (still on the hero part).

The way it works is that the player should always be in the middle of the screen and when he moves right, the background JPanel and all the monsters will move the opposite direction giving the "illusion" of movement.

However, when I add the playerComponent to the JPanel, the Hero doesn't appear. The majority of stuff is divided into files to make it easier but when I add the HeroComponent to the JFrame it does work normally.

These are my relevant files:

The file for creating the JFrame and adding the JPanel:

```
public class GameWindow {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Hero hero;
    private GameBackgroundPanel backgroundPanel;

    public GameWindow(JFrame frame, Hero hero) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.hero = hero;
        backgroundPanel = new GameBackgroundPanel();
//        frame.add(backgroundPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setContentPane(backgroundPanel);
    }

    public void startWindow() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The file for creating the JPanel and adding the component(s) to it:

```
    public class GameBackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    public int backgroundX = 0, backgroundY = 0;
    private ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/se/liu/rodis915/mineIsAPicture/poggers.png");
    private Hero hero = new HeroA();

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
//        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        HeroToComponent heroComponent = new HeroToComponent(hero);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setOpaque(false);
        g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), backgroundX, backgroundY, getWidth(), getWidth(), null);
        add(heroComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

I assume it's something with the Layout of the JPanel, the order code lines or something of the sort.

I would also appreciate opinions about the movement idea; if I move the JPanel position, will everything inside also follow along? If yes, how would I achieve that goal? I was hopping to just add components to the JFrame but I can't add more than 1 so I'm kinda lost.

Thanks so much!

Comment: ChatGPT just suggested a JFrame with a null layout. I tested it and it appears like it worked. Is there a problem with this? (Many say JFrame MUST have a layout)

Comment: I don't think you should be adding a component to a panel in the panel's `paintComponent` method. For me, looking at the code where you think the problem is, is not a good debug method. I suggest that you try to post a [mcve].

Comment: I tried to add it from the same place I add the JPanel to the JFrame, first I added the components to the JPanel and then added the JPanel to the JFrame but that didn't work.

As for making it shorter, I don't think I can because based on my current abilities the code I provided seems minimal, taking away anything should hinder any help.

These 2 files are the only ones that matter. The rest just makes the JComponent for the hero and such.

I'm currently trying the null Layout for the JFrame and it is working nicely so it has to be the Layout, that is also the only part I dont understand

Comment: Never alter your component in a paintComponent method.  You don’t control when paintComponent gets called—the system decides when to call it.  And it can be called for all sorts of reasons, most of which are beyond your control.  A paint method can *read* state in order to decide what to draw, but must not alter a component’s state.  Remove setLayout, remove setOpaque, remove add.  Do those things in the constructor, not in paintComponent.  Oh, and ChatGPT doesn’t care about being right, it just combines and dumps search results, dressed up in some nice grammar.

Comment: *I'm currently trying the null Layout for the JFrame and it is working nicely*. [Probably not for long](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)
You should absolutely not be adding components in `paintComponent` and you might need to (re)size explicitly components of a null layout

Comment: Putting setOpaque and such in the constructor of the component instead of in the paintComponent worked! I now can control those things from the HeroToComponent rather than in the main game file (which is a lot nicer).

I will try to rewrite the code so the frame has a layout. However, if I add components to the JPanel and move the JPanel, will the components move with it?

Essentially I don't really know how a JPanel differs from a JComponent. The idea is just to have it as a background image that can be moved. The enemies' components should move with it but not the heroComponent.